# UILabelのsizeToFitを無効にするには？

Tags: uikit, uilabel

時計アプリをつくっています。（針ではなくデジタル風の数字で表すタイプです。）UILabelをつかって時間を表示しているのですが、時間を表す数字が変わっていく度に、UILabelのサイズがリサイズされ、表示している数字のフォントも微妙に左右に動いてしまいます。iPhone等の時計アプリのように自然な感じしたいのですが、どうすればよいのでしょうか？　sizeToFitが原因なのかな？と思っているのですが、ストーリーボードでUILabelを配置しただけで、コードで指示はしていません。等幅フォントを使えば解決するのかも知れませんが、そういうフォントは使用可能なのでしょうか？　よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

「UILabelのサイズがリサイズされ」ているのかどうか、私は疑問を持ちますが、「表示している数字のフォントも微妙に左右に動」くのは、私の経験と一致しています。その原因は、「等幅フォントを使えば解決するのかも知れません」と推察なさっていることからおわかりのように、等幅でないプロポーショナルなフォントであるために、数字ひとつひとつの幅が異なることにあります。
ですから、等幅フォントを使用するというのが、唯一にして最善の解決法になります。ただし、数字の幅が同じであればよく、全文字が等幅のフォントである必要はありません。
とくにフォントを指定せず、システムフォントを使用するのなら、`UIFont`クラスのクラスメソッド`class func monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(_ fontSize: CGFloat, weight weight: CGFloat) -> UIFont`を使うといいでしょう。

*ViewControllerクラス内*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // digitLabelは、時刻を表示するラベル。
    digitLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(55.0, weight: UIFontWeightBlack)
}
```

`55.0`はフォントサイズの指定。適宜指定してください。`UIFontWeightBlack`は、フォントのウェイト（太さ）の定数（Constant）。`UIFontDescriptor`のクラスリファレンス内に、全ウェイトのリストがあります。

[image: iOSシミュレータ]

iOSシミュレータによる、表示結果です。上はただのシステムフォント。下は「monospacedDigitSystemFont」です。数字の"1"の幅が異なることがわかります。

Comment: monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize という便利なメソッドがあったのですね。帰ったら試してみます。（今会社なので・・・）ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: 実際に試してみました。うまく行きました。どうもありがとうございました。